# Magento order notification through sms for admin

Tags: sales-order, magento1.9.3

Is there any way to alert admin when order is placed from customer other than email like SMS etc. If it is there, anyone can share the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use some extensions as below :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-notification-by-sms.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-notification-sms-text-message.html

But i prefer below extension as it worked fine for me :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-sms-sms-notification-sms-marketing-1.html and this extension charge/sms

Comment: Is there any extension or ways for free? @Baby in Magento

Comment: for my knowledge , there is no free extension, but they will provide free trail period , so that you can test and use it.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, THE ABOVE LINKS ARE NOT WORKING